# Password Confirm Password Validation Check

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular 2 the latest release. I am trying to check if the password in Password field and Confirm Password are the same. Or if the the both fields match. Here is what i did so far, but It doesn't seem to be working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Signup.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Validators, FormGroup, FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }
  onSignup() {
    console.log("Logged in");
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
      ])],
      password: ['', Validators.compose([
          Validators.required,
      ])],
      confirmPassword: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,

      ])],
    });
  }
}
```

Signup.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSignup()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
      <small [hidden]="myForm.controls.email.valid || (myForm.controls.email.pristine && !myForm.submitted)" class="text-danger">
        Email is required.
      </small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" validateEqual="confirmPassword" reverse="true">
      <small [hidden]="myForm.controls.password.valid || (myForm.controls.password.pristine && !myForm.submitted)" class="text-danger">
        Password is required
      </small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="confirmPassword">Retype password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" validateEqual="password" reverse="false">
      <small [hidden]="myForm.controls.confirmPassword.valid || (myForm.controls.confirmPassword.pristine && !myForm.submitted)" class="text-danger">
        Password mismatch
      </small>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!myForm.valid" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Validator.ts

```
import { Directive, forwardRef, Attribute } from '@angular/core';
import { Validator, AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';
@Directive({
    selector: 'validator',
    providers: [
        { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => EqualValidator), multi: true }
    ]
})
export class EqualValidator implements Validator {
    constructor( @Attribute('validateEqual') public validateEqual: string,
                 @Attribute('reverse') public reverse: string) {
    }
    private get isReverse() {
        if (!this.reverse) return false;
        return this.reverse === 'true' ? true: false;
    }
    validate(c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } {
        // self value
        let v = c.value;
        // control vlaue
        let e = c.root.get(this.validateEqual);
        // value not equal
        if (e && v !== e.value && !this.isReverse) {
            return {
                validateEqual: false
            }
        }

        // value equal and reverse
        if (e && v === e.value && this.isReverse) {
            delete e.errors['validateEqual'];
            if (!Object.keys(e.errors).length) e.setErrors(null);
        }
        // value not equal and reverse
        if (e && v !== e.value && this.isReverse) {
            e.setErrors({
                validateEqual: false
            })
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working plunk which hooked into the value changing to monitor the values directly and set the errors.

I'm sure there are more clever solutions that can be found or thought of.

http://plnkr.co/PXcae8kq9quYFQC2x7K2

```
 subscribeToFormChangesAndSetValidity() {
      const myFormValueChanges$ = this.myForm.controls["passwords"].valueChanges;

      myFormValueChanges$.subscribe(x => {
          if(x.password === x.confirmPassword) {
              this.myForm.controls["passwords"].setErrors(null);
          } else {
              this.myForm.controls["passwords"].setErrors({ "notValid" : true});
          }
      });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      passwords: this.fb.group({
        password: ['', Validators.required],
        confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required]
        })
        });

        this.subscribeToFormChangesAndSetValidity();
  }
```

Comment: I looked at this one, but I am using [formGroup] they are using ngModel, they dont work together.

Comment: I updated my code, can you look at it please @silentsod